# Finding significant differences between slopes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, change-point

I have a graph showing a continuous variable plotted against a discrete variable:
[image: graph]

I'm looking to identify the point of diminishing returns or the point at which the slopes from two points on the x-axis are significantly different from one another. For example,it looks like the slope betwen points 3-4 is different from that of the slopes from points 4-5.

Someone recommended me using a chow test to do this, however, as far as I can tell, to do that it needs to be a linear regression, which this is not. If my understanding is correct both variables need to be continuous for linear regression.

Ideally, the results of whatever test I use would be a table of pairwise comparisons of each level on the x-axis and a column indicating if the slopes are different from one another or not.

Does anyone have any insight as to how I can go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Discrete x are no problem for linear regression (arguably in many cases even discrete y are not much of a problem; ultimately all real data are discrete).

Comment: Note that you cannot test in an isolated manner whether the slope between 3 and 4 is different from the slope between 4 and 5, as for this you'd only have three points and two differences on the y-axis, not enough to assess variation and construct a test.

Comment: What the Chow test does is that it tests whether a regression for all points left of a value is the same as a regression for all points right of it, or whether two regressions with different parameters left and right fit the data significantly better. This may be fine for you although it doesn't do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Chow test assumes that you know the (potential) change point. You could run the Chow test for each point, however this would imply multiple testing with increased type I error probabilities (the probability to find a significant value of the test at *any* change point is higher than to find something at a fixed change point even if in fact there is no true change point). There's some literature about testing for a regression change point at any location, see, e.g., https://www.jstor.org/stable/4355772

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHennig! Will likely go to a professor for some additional help but your insight is really helpful.